# Error: Undefined Offset, need to pass values to the Select Statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm getting the below error in order to achieve passing values to the "select" statement.

> Undefined Offset Error on statement `print_r($fieldName[$enID]);`

Code looks like

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                            {
                                $counter1 = $counter++;     
                                $fieldName[] = $row['fieldName'];
                                $fieldText[] = htmlspecialchars($row['fieldText']);
                                $fieldID[]   = $row['ID'];
                                $enID   = $row['ID'];
                                echo "$enID";
                                print_r($fieldName[$enID]);
//$enfieldText = $mysqli->query("SELECT fieldText FROM languageUpdate WHERE fieldName = '$row["fieldName"]' and Language = 'en'")->fetch_object()->fieldText; ##NEED HELP IN FIXING THIS

                                if ($_GET['showname']){     

                                echo"<tr>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['fieldName']."</td>";
                                echo '<td>'.'<input type = "text" class="form-control" onclick ="colorChange(this)" disabled = "disabled" id ="'.$row["ID"].'"  name = "fieldText['.$row["ID"].']" value = "'.$row["fieldText"].'">'."</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";}


                            }
```

My code fetches `ID, Name and Text` from database,and what I'm trying to do is to fetch some another data from the same table but by capturing the `Name` field extracted earlier. Basically, a nested information is being pulled. I'm getting an undefined offset on line: `print_r($fieldName[$enID])`. I'm capturing this in order to pass it to the next line to get one unique value, but I'm not able to do so.

example:

Lets say: while fetching results: `$fieldName[] Array ( [0] => title [1] => listHeading )`

I'm hoping to extract `title, and listHeading` and pass it to the

```
//$enfieldText = $mysqli->query("SELECT fieldText FROM languageUpdate WHERE fieldName = 'title'")->fetch_object()->fieldText; ##dynamic parameterization
```

Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: What is wrong with `$mysqli->query("SELECT fieldText FROM languageUpdate WHERE fieldName = '$row["fieldName"]' and Language = 'en'")` as you have it, currently commented out?

Comment: Error: Array to string conversion in line..

Comment: You have misaligned quotes. You are using double quotes surrounding fieldName, `'$row["fieldName"]'` but you are using double quotes to quote the string, `"SELECT ..."`. Try `$row['fieldName'].